# Parsing FQDN and item from Event Log

Tags: javascript, regex

I receive this event text and I need to be able to parse out the FQDN for each line along with the aspect name. I have tried several FQDN regex examples and the only that came close is `^[^.]+` but that still only captured the hostname, which I would be fine with. But I cannot seem to capture both sets of data.

Example:

Line: Test1.test.local System Reserved 73.2 %

Output:

FQDN = Test1.test.local

Aspect Name = System Reserved

```
'Performance Disk Utilization Exceeds 50%' threshold
 
Description: Average disk utilization during the past 2 minutes exceeds 50%
 
New Items (11)
 
Occurred at 10/21/2021 10:38:06 AM
 
Display Name Aspect Name Aspect Value
Test1.test.local System Reserved 73.2 %
Test1-stage.test.local System Reserved 69.3 %
test-stage.test.local \\?\Volume{c2e5b983-0000-0000-0000-006225000000}\ 83.3 %
test2.test.local System Reserved 73.2 %
test2.test.local E:\ - Data 62.5 %
test.test.LOCAL System Reserved 69.3 %
test.test.LOCAL \\?\Volume{0833abcb-0000-0000-0000-006225000000}\ 83.3 %
test3.test.local System Reserved 69.4 %
test3.test.local E:\ - SCCM 85.7 %
test3.cdp.local C:\ 53.1 %
test3.cdp.local \\?\Volume{fa03c719-0000-0000-0000-f0e17c000000}\ 83.3 %
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use 2 capture groups and match the number at the end followed by a percentage sign:

```
([^\s.]+(?:\.[^\s.]+)+) (.+?) \d+(?:\.\d+)? %
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s.]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitspace char or `.`
  - `(?:\.[^\s.]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching a dot followed by 1+ chars other than a whitspace char or `.` to match at least a single dot
- `)` Close group 1
- `(.+?)`  Capture 1 or more digits in **group 2** between 2 spaces
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)? %` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part and  `%`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VqyV3O/1)

```js
const regex = /([^\s.]+(?:\.[^\s.]+)+) (.+?) \d+(?:\.\d+)? %/gm;
const str = `Test1.test.local System Reserved 73.2 %
Test1-stage.test.local System Reserved 69.3 %
test-stage.test.local \\\\?\\Volume{c2e5b983-0000-0000-0000-006225000000}\\ 83.3 %
test2.test.local System Reserved 73.2 %
test2.test.local E:\\ - Data 62.5 %
test.test.LOCAL System Reserved 69.3 %
test.test.LOCAL \\\\?\\Volume{0833abcb-0000-0000-0000-006225000000}\\ 83.3 %
test3.test.local System Reserved 69.4 %
test3.test.local E:\\ - SCCM 85.7 %
test3.cdp.local C:\\ 53.1 %
test3.cdp.local \\\\?\\Volume{fa03c719-0000-0000-0000-f0e17c000000}\\ 83.3 %`;

console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => ({
  "FQDN": m[1],
  "AspectName": m[2]
})));
```